# Can not import public EC key in jwk format suptile

Tags: javascript, webcrypto-api

I am using Chrome and I want to import this public EC P-256 ECDH key like so:

```js
await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    {
      kty: "EC",
      crv: "P-256",
      ext: true,
      x: "mRBuuxrvM7xy2oc4xZkw_i0JyIiIp_b0Zmnb1RYKZcg",
      y: "emhIhswnvIHICDtkWx4LLWy3HcN-is2l1oN9-r4_ChQ",
      key_ops: ["deriveKey"],
    },
    { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-256" },
    true,
    ["deriveKey"]
  );
```

However I get the error:  Cannot create a key using the specified key usages.

Why not?

Answer (score 0):

Ok so it turns out that when you want to import a public key to derive a key from it you should just not give any keyUssages to it. So this works:

```js
await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    "jwk",
    {
      kty: "EC",
      crv: "P-256",
      ext: true,
      x: "mRBuuxrvM7xy2oc4xZkw_i0JyIiIp_b0Zmnb1RYKZcg",
      y: "emhIhswnvIHICDtkWx4LLWy3HcN-is2l1oN9-r4_ChQ",
    }, 
    { name: "ECDH", namedCurve: "P-256" },
    true,
    [] // the public key just doesn't have usages 
  );
```